# Mass Transit publish not publishing message to Rabbitmq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

My configuration is shown below:
Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(config => {

    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) => {
        cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
    });
});
```

My publisher is shown below: StaffController.cs

```
public class StaffController(IPublishService publishService) : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        publishService.Publish(new AddStaffMessage 
        {
            ContactNumber = 9827279897,
            Name = "Prabesh Upreti"
        });
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

My message is not publishing to the rabbitmq server. I've tried changing the host different times by differently configuring it but it simple doesn't work. Help me.

Comment: Is the rabbitmq server local?  Anything in the logs that it's getting a connection?  Is it a firewall issue?   Has it ever worked?  If not, do you have the proper parameters to even connect to rabbitmq?  Exchange, route and queue.  I don't see that kind of setup in your code.  What about permissions?  Is ```username``` permitted to send messages to that particular server?  There's just a lot of information missing, it's hard to pinpoint what the issue could be.

Comment: What status code is being returned like 200 OK or a 400/500 error?  Or are you just getting an exception with no response?

Comment: `IPublishService` isn't a MassTransit interface. It's likely it can't connect to the broker, as with every single one of these questions, I'll just suggest you look at the logs in DEBUG and see what's happening.